# UUID.randomUUID -> java.lang.StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, random, uuid, stack-overflow

The title explains the problem I think, trying to create a random Id for an Object, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.security.provider.ByteArrayAccess.b2iBig64(ByteArrayAccess.java:274)
at sun.security.provider.SHA.implCompress(SHA.java:122)
at sun.security.provider.SHA.implDigest(SHA.java:103)
at sun.security.provider.DigestBase.engineDigest(DigestBase.java:186)
at sun.security.provider.DigestBase.engineDigest(DigestBase.java:165)
at java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineDigest(MessageDigest.java:576)
at java.security.MessageDigest.digest(MessageDigest.java:353)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:226)
at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:455)
at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:145)
```

I don't think that anyone can tell me what is going on since I provide little information -> I know that.
The thing is: I have not any other information, I just create a randomUUID and it crashes.
So I'm just asking for ideas, since I don't find any googling this exception.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Answer provided by
m0skit0 and scotth
Without noticing that the method which lead to an object creating a UUID was called nonstop I - well - did not notice that a huge amount of UUIDs was generated, which lead to the stackoverflow.
Thank you!

Comment: It would be better if you paste the exact code.

Comment: too bad you can't provide OS, JVM version, etc

Comment: Wild guess: are you using recursion? Also I think your stacktrace is incomplete.

Comment: -from - at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:145) - on it only refers to my classes, which only create a new variable, which creates a random UUID, so this would not help (or am I wrong? Noob I am)
Java: 1.7.0_51; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_51-b13
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; de_DE (jmonkeyplatform)

Comment: it seems more people are looking for this bug https://bukkit.atlassian.net/browse/BUKKIT-2529

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers btw. :)

Comment: Looking at that bug report it looks more like the application had a pending stack overflow within itself and just happened to run out of stack frames when calling UUID.randomUUID() which might take several stack frames of its own. The application is in a deep recursive or infinite loop much like @m0skit0 indicates.  UUID may just be the victim of too-few-stack-frames left. See https://bukkit.atlassian.net/secure/attachment/13700/crash-2012-09-18_18.48.18-server.txt

Comment: So in other words, please post your own code that is calling randomUUID() because it is likely you are in a recursive or infinite loop in your own code.

Comment: You guys (m0skit0, scotth) have been right.
It was recursive but NOT meant to be, I passed a wrong parameter which caused the method, creating an Object that has a UUID, to call itself nonstop.
Thank you very for the hints!! :D

Comment: Voted to close.  This root cause of the OP's problem is unrelated to the Question ... and the Question is essentially a "red herring", and unlikely to helpful to anyone in the future.